# Get not regular XML values

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I got the XML from the GPS internet service. It is look like:

[image: Not regular XML]

I need to get X and Y values from it, but I don't know how to do this

I tried with Descendants XDocument property but its failed to retrieve values.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He is my solution

```
gpsResponseXML.Descendants("Property").Where(el => el.Attribute("Name").Value == "X").Attributes("Value").FirstOrDefault().Value)
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like `.Elements("Property").Where(el=>el.Attribute("Name").Value == "X")`

That should give you the element with X attribute, after that you just pick the value of any attribute of that element.

Comment: Thanks you gave me an idea for solution
See my solution above

Answer (score 1):

```
        var el = XElement.Parse(xml);
        var x = el.Elements("Property").Where(e => e.Attribute("Name").Value == "X").Single().Attribute("Value").Value;
        var y = el.Elements("Property").Where(e => e.Attribute("Name").Value == "Y").Single().Attribute("Value").Value;
```

OR

```
        var x = el.Elements("Property").ElementAt(3).Attribute("Value").Value;
        var y = el.Elements("Property").ElementAt(4).Attribute("Value").Value;
```